# Use mathpazo for body and math but use a non-tex font (in this case Futura) for headings.

Tags: xetex, mathpazo

I have a document that so far has used mathpazo for everything.  I love the texlive distributed Palatino for maths and body text.  The small caps in particular are much better than the True Type Palatino on my Mac.  However, I want to use my True Type Futura for headings.  Thus I decided to use xetex. All is well except I can't work out how to load up Futura without unloading mathpazo.  I can use fontspec to load up the True Type Palatino, but that is a big demotion for by body text.  I want mathpazo for everything except headings and to use my True Type Futura for headings.

Comment: Opentype versions of TeX Gyre Pagella (which is based on URW Palladio, i.e., the text font mathpazo loads) are available for free on CTAN as well as [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/). In fact, you may already have the files. It is also possible on Linux at least (not sure about mac) to [make all the TeXlive fonts available system-wide](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-360003.4.5) (and thus to XeTeX).

Comment: Oh, and if you want a TrueType version of URW Palladio, you can get it from Ghostscript's SVN repo [here](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/ghostpdl/urwfonts/). TeX Gyre Pagella is probably easier to work with, however.

Comment: Thanks, these useful comments probably qualify as answers :)

Comment: frabjous, I have taken your advice and it is working perfectly.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that in the long run you will be very happy with the combination of mathpazo (which needs an encoding like  T1 or OT1) and xelatex for normal texts: You won't be able to use a lot of non-ascii chars in the input, e.g. euro and sharp-s will not work. Apart from this: If you want to use a "fontspec font" in the heading you must change the encoding to EU1:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\fontencoding{EU1}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ABC}
blub sharp-s:ß euro:€
\end{document}
```